# I'm looking to download a file (picture) via wifi where it updates every 15 minutes

Tags: wifi

I have a Model A (RCA output, not VGA) and [this USB wireless dongle.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003MTTJOY) Can I just use wget to constantly grab a picture from a server / website and the fbi command to display it?  I'm looking to essentially have a digital picture frame but it pulls from a server.  Any help on getting started or recommended libraries to use for this stuff?

Answer (score 1):

`crontab` to schedule jobs like downloading and displaying the image
`wget` to download a file from a http/ftp server
alternatively `scp` to download a file via ssh